# How to fix running problems in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c

When I click on "build and run" button in Code::Blocks, it opens a file (a tab beside the main file) containing "stdio.h" codes automatically and does not run the program. Then, when I click on "run" button, it tells that it has not been built.
Could you please help me to fix that?

Comment: Take a look at the *build log*. You probably have some build errors.

Comment: It is probably reporting some build error, where the error was detected while parsing <stdio.h> - the error is in that case probably in come code that occurred before <stdio.h> was included.  Post the code you are attempting to build, and the build log.  My guess is that when you actually _read_ the log, you will discover your problem, or be able to ask a more specific question!  Unless you post some C code, your question is not about C (as tagged) but rather about Code::Blocks.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation. The error was in <stdio.h> codes, I could correct it.